# Extracting data from gmail into a spreadsheet using Google Apps scripts

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Case: I receive notifications through email for work with evaluations of the personal security system. This is what they look like (I blacked out some pieces because of privacy laws)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ye1l.png)

I want to extract some information from this email to google sheets through Google Apps Script (javascript language)

So far I have only managed to extract the date from the email into Google sheets, with this code:

```
function onOpen(e){
  
    ui.createMenu("Tessa").addItem("Get Emails by Label", "getGmailEmails").addToUi();  //create button in google sheets, which will be used to add information from incoming emails to Google sheets. 
  
}

function getGmailEmails(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("tobeprocessed");    //get emails with label 'tobeprocessed' (could also be another name).
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  
  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.isUnread()){
        extractDetails(message);
        GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
      }
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);   //delete label after processing the message, so that it won't be added twice (or more if you press the button again)
    
  }
  
}

function extractDetails(message){
  
  var emailData = {
    Locatie: "Null",
    Score: "Null",
    Datum: "Null",
    Opmerking: "Null",
  }
  var emailKeywords = {
    Locatie: "",
    Score: " ",
    Opmerking: "",
  }
  
  emailData.Datum = message.getDate();

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  var emailDataArr = [];
  
  for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
  }
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
```

Can someone please help me out with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the message in the body of the email using [getPlainBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getplainbody), which returns a string with the body contents.

After that, one way to retrieve pieces of the body would be to use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function extractDetails(message){
  var emailData = {
    Locatie: "Null",
    Score: "Null",
    Datum: "Null",
    Opmerking: "Null",
  }
  
  emailData.Datum = message.getDate();

  // Get the email's body
  var body = message.getPlainBody();
  //var body = 'Reno Vught van Heikant heeft een MIRS-melding gemaakt waarin het functioneren van het persoonsbeveiliging systeem werd beoordeeld met een 3.Toelichting melder: gaf locatie woonkamer aan terwijl ik bijna op de boerderij was. ik kwam vanuit de woonkamer rennen.Beschrijving incident: bij binnenkomst gebeurde er dit. en toen dit';

  // Retrieves everything between "van " and " heeft"
  var locatieRegex = /van (.*?) heeft/s;
  var match = body.match(locatieRegex);
  if (match.length > 1) {
    emailData.Locatie = match[1];
  } 

  // Retrieves everything between "met een " and a period (.)
  var scoreRegex = /met een (.*?)\./s;
  match = body.match(scoreRegex);
  if (match.length > 1) {
    emailData.Score = match[1];
  } 

  // Retrieves everything between "Toelichting melder: " and "Beschrijving incident:"
  var opmerkingRegex = /Toelichting melder: (.*?)Beschrijving incident:/s; 
  match = body.match(opmerkingRegex);
  if (match.length > 1) {
    emailData.Opmerking = match[1];
  }


  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  var emailDataArr = [];
  
  for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
  }
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much!! this has been very helpful already. I have a question: I can delete the 'emailKeywords' variable, right? If I add your part of the code and delete variable 'emailKeywords', I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null'. Looks like the email's body content is null. I have already tried putting !=null after the variable body, then the error is: 'TypeError: body.match is not a function. Also, I have tried putting the email body itself as a string in the variable string, to see if this would give output, but then I get the first error as well.

Comment: Yes, you can delete `emailKeywords`. The sample code I posted was based on a redacted image, so you're probably getting that error because the actual text is different. Check if the body has the same text as it's shown on the image you posted: `Logger.log(message.getPlainBody())`. If it doesn't you probably have to adjust the regular expressions to work with the actual body.

Comment: Hi, I used the Logger.log(message.getPlainBody()) to check if the body has the same text as it's shown on the image, and it looks to me like it does... I added the image in my question above, can you maybe look at it? Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of an image, please paste that string that is returned by `Logger.log(message.getPlainBody())` so it's easier to copy and test. You can replace sensitive data with anything.

Comment: okay, i have pasted the string that was returned by that line!

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer to work based on the string that you provided and to be more explicit with error handling. Note that, as I said before, you might need to adapt the regular expressions if you get a body with a structure different than this one.