# 'TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null'

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Case: I want to extract some information from gmail to google sheets about the evaluation of a personal security system.
I have managed to extract the date and now I want to extract some information regarding the email's body content (like score of the personal security system and comments about it)

this is my code:

```
function onOpen(e){
  
    ui.createMenu("Tessa").addItem("Get Emails by Label", "getGmailEmails").addToUi();  //create button in google sheets, which will be used to add information from incoming emails to Google sheets. 
  
}

function getGmailEmails(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("tobeprocessed");    //get emails with label 'tobeprocessed' (could also be another name).
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  
  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.isUnread()){
        extractDetails(message);
        GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
      }
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);   //delete label after processing the message, so that it won't be added twice (or more if you press the button again)
    
  }
  
}

function extractDetails(message){
  var emailData = {
    Locatie: "Null",
    Score: "Null",
    Datum: "Null",
    Opmerking: "Null",
  }
  
  emailData.Datum = message.getDate();

  // Get the email's body
  var body = message.getPlainBody();

  // Retrieves everything between "van " and " heeft"
  var locatieRegex = /van (.*) heeft/s;
  emailData.Locatie = String(body).match(locatieRegex)[1];

  // Retrieves everything between "beoordeeld met een " and a period (.)
  var scoreRegex = /beoordeeld met een (.*)\.Toelichting melder:/s;
  emailData.Score = String(body).match(scoreRegex)[1];

  // Retrieves everything between "Toelichting melder: " and "Beschrijving incident:"
  var opmerkingRegex = /Toelichting melder: (.*)Beschrijving incident:/s; 
  emailData.Opmerking = String(body).match(opmerkingRegex)[1];


  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  var emailDataArr = [];
  
  for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
  }
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
}
```

This code gives me the error:

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null'

Looks like the email's body content is null. I have already tried putting !=null after the variable body, then the error is:

> 'TypeError: body.match is not a function.

Also, I have tried putting the email body itself as a string in the variable body, to see if this would give output, but then I get the first error as well.

Does anybody have an idea of what I did wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null* means there was no match. First, always check if there is a match before getting the `[1]` item. Also, make sure your `body` is a string, if it is not, you can use `.match()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I added the email body content. There has to be a match, right? And i also tried String(body) but that doesn't work either...

Comment: There is no match for the `werd met (.*)\.` regex.

Comment: you are right, thanks! If I paste the message in the var body (like a string), then it runs now and I indeed get the right output. But if I use the message.getPlainBody() function again, it still returns that error... Do you have any suggestions? Is there another function I could use maybe? I have put the renewed code in the question above, so you can see what I did.

Comment: As mentioned in your first question about this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68825547/3751868), the string returned by `message.getPlainBody()` might not be exactly like the one you see on the email, so you probably need to adjust the regular expressions to work with the actual body.

Comment: Please make sure you test against the same *string* as in the original mail.